# How to handle a right click on a ListViewItem when ListView has an ItemTemplate?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, uwp

I have a ListView which is bound to a ViewModel.
I want to select the ListViewItem which is right clicked and also a trigger to happen to change a ViewModel attribute.(Selection mode to be single).

```
<ListView MinHeight="50" MaxHeight="120" 
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DisplayItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedDisplayItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SelectedDisplayItemTemplate}" 
IsItemClickEnabled="False"
helpers:AttachedCommand.Command="{Binding Path=Commands[NavigateToDisplayItem]}"
helpers:AttachedCommand.Event="Tapped" />
```

I have tried handling the Right Tapped event in the ListView but I couldn't get the item that was tapped. How do I change the selected item on right click and also set SelectedDisplayItem as the Right clicked item if selected?

Comment: Since you are setting `ItemTemplate` to `SelectedDisplayItemTemplate` what happens when you set your `RightTapped` event there?

Comment: Well since its a template and gets its content from a style file I wouldn't want to put a RightTapped there.

Comment: Maybe you could make your itemtemplate as a usercontrol and handle RightTapped in there.

Answer (score 0):

Try make it with Behaviors

```
<ListView
    x:Name MainListView
    MinHeight="50" 
    MaxHeight="120" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayItems}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDisplayItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SelectedDisplayItemTemplate}">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
         <core:EventTriggerBehavior
             EventName="RightTapped">
             <core:InvokeCommandAction
                  Command="{Binding YourCommand}"
                  CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MainListView, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
   </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ListView>
```